# How to upgrade fullcalendar version 4.4 in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Actually, I want upgrade fullcalendar version 4.4 in my angularjs web application. already have fullcalendar version 2.9 it very slow in my project that's i want to upgrade fullcalendar version 4.4 so please help how to upgrade this and i have tried but i'm not able to get  please check my code below.

@ Note  : All the js and css code i have included footer.php & header.php

Html code:

```
<div id='calendar44'></div>
```

ctrl.ordercal.js : this js all the code blow init function.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#calendar44'));
     lg(calendarEl);    
     alert(calendarEl);
     var calendarout = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ]});
     alert(calendarout);    
        calendarout.render();       
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem with that code? Do you get a Console error? Or some other problem? Simply saying "I'm not able to get" doesn't allow us to understand the problem at all. I think `var calendarEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#calendar44'));` is wrong though, it should be simply `var calendarEl = document.querySelector('#calendar44');` . I don't know Angular so I don't know what `angular.element()` does, but I would guess it produces an object that `new FullCalendar.Calendar` cannot use - it requires a standard DOM element, as shown in all documentation and examples.